# ReactJs how to increment/decrement numbers right of decimal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, numbers, decimal

I'm using react js. Basically, I have an input field with the increment and decrement buttons on the right side of the input field. When I increment the field, the number on the right side of the decimal is getting incremented instead of the number on the left side. Not sure how to do this as it seems others are not asking this question. Or the behavior is weird. Please see the code and image below. Thanks!

Input component:

```
    <FormLabel component="legend" style={{ marginBottom: '8px' }}>
      Hide Balances Below
    </FormLabel>
    <FormControl>
      <Input
        name="amount"
        type="number"
        inputProps={{ step: 'any' }}
        value={dustThreshold}
        onChange={e => setDustThreshold(e.target.value)}
        endAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="end">
            {ellipsize('BTC', this.ELLIPSE_LENGTH)}
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        className={classes.input}
        disableUnderline
      />
    </FormControl>
```

[image]

Basically trying to get the values on the right side(.00001666) to increment and decrement instead of where the '30' is(left of decimal)

Comment: this is not react problem, you just need to add step with spesific decimal place. `step=".00000001"`

Comment: Thanks! That did it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not react problem, you just need to add step with spesific decimal place. `step=".00000001"`

```html
<input
 name="amount"
 type="number"
 step=".00000001"
 value="30.00001666"/>
```